# Skipping files in spec/ when running rcov with RSpec 2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rcov

When running `rake spec:rcov` for a Rails 3 application, the files in the `spec/` directory are getting included in the coverage statistics, but I don't want them to be. I want coverage statistics only for my actual application.

In older versions of RSpec, it was possible to customize this with a `spec/rcov.opts` file with the line `--exclude "spec/*"` but it seems that file is no longer read by Rspec 2. I tried creating a `.rcov` file since `spec/spec.opts` changed to `.rspec`, but that didn't get read either.

I've found some documentation on how to do this when defining a rake task, but I'd rather not overwrite the provided rake task — it seems like this must be something other people have tried to do as well.

How can I customize the files that are excluded from coverage statistics?

For reference, the versions of all relevant gems I'm using are:

```
rails (3.0.5)
rake (0.8.7)
rcov (0.9.9)
rspec (2.5.0,)
rspec-core (2.5.1)
rspec-expectations (2.5.0,)
rspec-mocks (2.5.0)
rspec-rails (2.5.0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [RSpec Upgrade file](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/features/Upgrade.md):

> In RSpec-1, the rake task would read
>   in rcov options from an `rcov.opts`
>       file. This is ignored by RSpec-2. RCov options are now set directly on
>   the Rake
>       task:
>
> ```
>     RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rcov) do |t|
>       t.rcov_opts =  %q[--exclude "spec"]
>     end
> ```

Inspecting the `rspec-rails` source code I found the library defines the `:rcov` task and it doesn't seem to exclude the rspec folder.

```
desc "Run all specs with rcov"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:rcov => spec_prereq) do |t|
  t.rcov = true
  t.pattern = "./spec/**/*_spec.rb"
  t.rcov_opts = '--exclude /gems/,/Library/,/usr/,lib/tasks,.bundle,config,/lib/rspec/,/lib/rspec-'
end
```

You might want to remove the task and recreate it with your own settings or define a new task.

Comment: Setting the options when defining a new rake task is fairly simple -- I'm looking for a way to customize the existing task like you could with Rspec 1. Although I guess this is what I'll be doing if it turns out that's not possible.

Comment: You can't. You have to unload the existing task and redefine it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that this is the way to go. Too bad they removed the ability to customize it.